# Bash function condition comand argument misinterprets strangely and wrongly Ubuntu as Alpine

Tags: bash, shell-script

I readjusted the code to detect the distribution package manager and added the new arguments to capture the values:

```bsh
get_package_manager_install()
{
  if   [ -x "$(command -v $1)" ]; then echo "$1 add --no-cache $2";  # apk add --no-cache
  elif [ -x "$(command -v $1)" ]; then echo "$1 install -y $2";      # apt install -y
  elif [ -x "$(command -v $1)" ]; then echo "$1 install -y $2";      # dnf install -y
  elif [ -x "$(command -v $1)" ]; then echo "$1 -av $2";             # emerge -av
  elif [ -x "$(command -v $1)" ]; then echo "$1 -S --noconfirm $2";  # pacman -S --noconfirm
  elif [ -x "$(command -v $1)" ]; then echo "$1 in $2";              # zypper in
  else        
    echo "Unknown manager manager" &>/dev/null
  fi
}
```

And executing the functions by entering with two arguments:

```
get_package_manager_install 'apk'     "musl-locale"
get_package_manager_install 'apt'     "locales locales-all"
get_package_manager_install 'dnf'     "glibc"
get_package_manager_install 'emerge'  "sys-libs/glibc"
get_package_manager_install 'pacman'  "glibc"
get_package_manager_install 'zypper'  "glibc"
```

I ran it on Ubuntu, and the output showed:

```bsh
apt add --no-cache locales locales-all
```

It appears that the function thinks Ubuntu is Alpine, due to `if   [ -x "$(command -v $1)" ]; then echo "$1 add --no-cache $2"`, but currently, it should be `elif [ -x "$(command -v $1)" ]; then echo "$1 install -y $2"` that would output `locales locales-all`.

Comment: I think you need to think through your logic a bit. For example, under what circumstances does `command -v $1` first fail and then succeed without changing `$1`?

Comment: If I replace `command -v $1` with the normal commands, all the commands will appear. If I keep `command -v $1` and replace the second `$1`s with normal commands, then the command `apk add --no-cache` still would appear.

Comment: @GustavoReis, if `$1` is some command that exists, such that `[ -x "$(command -v $1)" ]` is true, then it'll be true every time it's tested, so the first `then` branch runs and the `elif` conditions aren't tested.

Comment: You should probably check the actual value of `$1` when deciding what arguments it takes.

Comment: @ilkkachu, I got what you meant. I simplified and cleaned the code, adding three arguments: `get_package_manager_install() { if [ -x "$(command -v $1)" ]; then  echo "$1 $2 $3"; else  echo "Unknown package manager" &>/dev/null; fi }`. The command will get the first argument and check if the command exists, and if other commands are checked, they will be sent into limbo while only one command will be valid.

Comment: I tested executing functions with three arguments: `get_package_manager_install "apk" "add --no-cache" "musl-locale"; get_package_manager_install "apt" "install -y"      "locales locales-all"`, and the output showed `apt install -y locales locales-all`. It was what you tried to explain to me. Thank you for your logic explanation!